# How do I select the right iPhone carrier

Tags: iphone, tethering, visual-voicemail, cellular-carriers

I have seen a lot of people asking about what carrier to use and what features they have.

Also people have asked about Visual Voicemail, which confusingly is not available on some networks, although Apple highlight it as one of the iPhone features, without mentioning it is not available to all carriers. [Source](http://www.apple.com/uk/iphone/built-in-apps/phone.html)

Also I have had many people ask about using a Personal Hotspot or unlocking the iPhone.

Where can all this information be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question so I could answer it, as I said there are a lot of people asking me about this issue.

On [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1937) of Apple's support website, you can find a list of worldwide carriers and the features they support on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

With Verizon, are you able to use the internet while you talk on the phone? I know that with AT&T you can.

Comment: do you mean browse with safari? then as far as I am aware you can with all iPhones. perhaps someone else answer this who has experienced the Verizon carrier network?

Comment: Unless you're connected to WiFi, you cannot talk and use data on a CDMA carrier (Verizon and Sprint here in the US) at the same time. Per the OP, you can indeed do that on a GSM network (AT&T and T-Mobile here in the states).